# How To Save <img> Tag Sources in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, filter

This is my first question here and I hope to receive your help.

My application receives HTML code from a website that I then want to display in a proper way.

For example I receive:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p>
<p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p>
<p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam/p>    
<p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p>
```

Now, I'd like to save each img tag source in an array. 
Using different filter methods, I know how to filter out the source of the first & last img tag but I can't filter them all.

I want to filter the plain text (no problem) and add the images in the end.

Any answer that helps to find a solution is appreciated! Thank you very much.

P.S. jQuery, Javascript etc. can be used. No PHP though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can se [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

```
var string = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p><p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p><p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam/p>    <p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p>';

var array = $(string).find('img').map(function(index, item){
    return $(item).attr('src')
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cN7FB/3/)

Comment: This takes all the img sources of the HTML file. Is there a way to reduce it to a string?
The thing is, I get the HTML as a string and I want to filter the string, not the whole page.

Comment: @Florian yes, you can do something like `$(string).find('img').map(...)`

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you. Let me know your Pay Pal if you like.

Answer (score 2):

native Js with filter Regex

```
var elms=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
function filterImgSrcToArray(elms){
    var array=[], count=0;
    var regex=arguments[1] || new RegExp(/.*/) ;
    for (var i=0;i<elms.length;i++){
        if (regex.test(elms[i].src)) array[count++]=elms[i].src;
    }
    return array;
}
console.log(filterImgSrcToArray(elms));
console.log(filterImgSrcToArray(elms,/pipi/)); //should be empty [] in your example
console.log(filterImgSrcToArray(elms,/\.png/)); //all *.png files in []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **push()** function of the jQuery,

```
var $imgsrc=[];
$('p').each(function(){
   $imgsrc.push($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
})
console.log($imgsrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use plain JavaScript, rather than jQuery, you could use:

```
Object.prototype.mapAttribute = function (attr) {
    if (!attr) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var test = this.length,
            that = test ? [] : [this],
            arr = [];
        if (test) {
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++){
                that[i] = this[i];
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = that[i].getAttribute(attr);
        }
        return arr;
    }
};
```

Call as follows:

```
var sources = document.getElementsByTagName('img').mapAttribute('src');
console.log(sources);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RAPrv/).

Or (for example):

```
var sources = document.getElementById('test').mapAttribute('src');
console.log(sources);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RAPrv/1/).

The above will get you the value from the attribute, so, for example in the following HTML:

```
<img src="images/testRelativePath.png" />
```

The value returned in the array would be:

```
['images/testRelativePath.png']
```

If you wanted, instead, the absolute path you could use:

```
Object.prototype.mapAttribute = function (attr) {
    if (!attr) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var test = this.length,
            that = test ? [] : [this],
            arr = [];
        if (test) {
            for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++){
                that[i] = this[i];
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = that[i][attr];
        }
        return arr;
    }
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RAPrv/2/).

Which will return (in the linked demo, look at the last value in the console):

```
"http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/images/testRelativePath.png"
```

And, while you've now accepted an answer, here's how to do the same using plain JavaScript:

```
Object.prototype.mapAttributeFromString = function (elem, attr) {
    if (!elem || !attr) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var div = document.createElement('div'),
            arr = [];
        div.innerHTML = this;
        var elems = div.getElementsByTagName(elem);
        for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
            arr[i] = elems[i].getAttribute(attr);
        }
        return arr;
    }
};

var HTML = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p><p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p><p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam/p><p><a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png"><img alt="Wiki" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bc/Wiki.png" width="600" height="534"></a></p>',
    sources = HTML.mapAttributeFromString('img','src');
console.log(sources);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RAPrv/4/).

Comment: This takes all the img sources of the HTML file. Is there a way to reduce it to a string? The thing is, I get the HTML as a string and I want to filter the string, not the whole page.